# pdf.js: Changing current page number programmatically

Tags: pdf.js

With pdf.js is there a way to programmatically change the current page of a PDF being viewed?  For example, a call to change the current page to page 5.

(I know that I can initially set the page by specifying the page number in the URL, but I want to change it programmatically after it has been opened.)

Answer (score 10):

`PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber` is [a getter and setter](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/d08895d6591b8b3233676a2ffa6a2c294cb70df7/web/pdf_viewer.js#L127-L158). Examples:

```
// Go to page 5
PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = 5;

// Move two pages forward
PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber += 2;
```

Comment: Awesome. ++++++

Comment: The following code results in the error: `TypeError: PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer is null`

    <script src="/pdfjs_es5/build/pdf.js"></script> 
    <script src="/pdfjs_es5/web/viewer.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = 5; 
    PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber += 1; 
    </script> 
    <body> <div id="menusurface2"> <iframe id="pdf-js-viewer" src="/pdfjs_es5/web/viewer.html?file=/books/book.pdf" title="webviewer" frameborder="0" width="500" height="600"></iframe> </div> </body>

What am I missing?

Comment: The following code results in the error: `TypeError: PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer is null`


    `<script src="/pdfjs_es5/build/pdf.js"></script> `
    `<script src="/pdfjs_es5/web/viewer.js"></script> `
    `<script> `
    `PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = 5; `
    `PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber += 1; `
    `</script> `
    `<body> <div id="menusurface2"> <iframe id="pdf-js-viewer" src="/pdfjs_es5/web/viewer.html?file=/books/book.pdf" title="webviewer" frameborder="0" width="500" height="600"></iframe> </div> </body> `


What am I missing?

Comment: I tested this and at first if failed, the I realized I was passing a string instead of a number. Make sure to pass a number and it works like a charm. Thank you very much for this!