# How to get the PDF page number of the currently displayed using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, pdf.js

I wrote the code to display the PDF using PDF.js.

I want to get the PDF page number of the currently displayed using javascript.

Also, I may be using `<object>` tag on html5

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do from the beginning. I don't also understand how to use pdf.js conversantly.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615248/pdf-js-changing-current-page-number-programmatically) approach works.

Comment: I'm not good at much English. I read a reference PDF.JS. However, I could not understand. I want to tell me so good even in the reference page.

Comment: Start from http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/ . If you want modify the demo viewer (http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html), you have to dive into code yourself.